# CrystalReport Always showing same data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to show the data programatically, but my code is showing data always the same. Same even I change the WHERE em.emp_id=5 or 6

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection c = frmMain.connect();

        rptEmpProf cryRpt = new rptEmpProf();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables ;
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = frmMain.dbSrvrName;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = frmMain.dbName;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = frmMain.dbUsrName;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = frmMain.dbPass;
        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        string q = "SELECT em.emp_id 'Employee ID', " +
            "em.emp_fname 'First Name', " +
            "em.emp_lname 'Last Name', " +
            "em.emp_phone 'Phone', " +
            "em.emp_email 'Email', " +
            "em.emp_addr 'Address', " +
            "em.emp_join_dt 'Join Date', " +
            "em.emp_salary 'Salary'," +
            "em.emp_card_no 'Card No.', " +
            "ds.dsg_name 'Designation', " +
            "dp.dept_name 'Department', " +
            "sf.sft_name 'Shift', " +
            "sc.sec_name 'Section' " +
        "FROM employee em INNER JOIN designations ds ON ds.dsg_id=em.emp_dsg_id " +
            "INNER JOIN sections sc ON sc.sec_id = ds.dsg_sec_id " +
            "INNER JOIN departments dp ON dp.dept_id = sc.sec_dept_id " +
            "INNER JOIN shifts sf ON sf.sft_id = em.emp_sft_id " +
        "WHERE em.emp_id = 6;";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

        frmMain.disconnect(c);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the data really differ when employeeId 5 or 6? Can u double check it?

Answer (score 0):

You are hard coded

```
 WHERE em.emp_id = 6
```

Please pass dynamically.
Debug: check your datable data First.

Comment: "Same even I change the WHERE em.emp_id=5 or 6" I think the OPs tried that.

Comment: I think your query is returning same data please debug and check it. Also check auto binding in database expert into the reportviewer

Comment: It is no problem. I see if I code hardly 5 to 6, it always shows 5 data

Comment: Does the data really differ when employeeId 5 or 6? Can u double check it?

Comment: @sarwar026 Yes. I checked it.... When I call for emp_id 5, it works fine. But when I call for emp_id 6, it still shows the data for 5...

Answer (score 0):

Raihan,

When you are using feeding a DataSet to a Crystal Report the most important things are:

1. What type of datasource you originally built the report from
2. That the dataset you are feeding it now is an *exact* match (same columns
   and types)

If this is done correctly, you should NOT need to be setting connection information and applying logon info to the report as you are doing here. (You'll only need that stuff to build your dataset. Crystal Reports doesn't care because it just needs that data, why would it care about the server/database/password when you are giving it already queried data?)

Here is an example of someone building a report from an XML datasource, then passing data:
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=9

You'll see that it's MUCH simpler than your copy. In fact, I think the reason you keep seeing the same data is because it's connecting to the server, etc. that your table logon info is specifying and using the default query that was used to build the report. Your dataset is being ignored.

Raihan, start by *removing* this code. What happens when you do this?

```
TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
Tables CrTables;

crConnectionInfo.ServerName = frmMain.dbSrvrName;
crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = frmMain.dbName;
crConnectionInfo.UserID = frmMain.dbUsrName;
crConnectionInfo.Password = frmMain.dbPass;
CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
}
```

Raihan, after doing what I wrote above, if it now prompts you this means it doesn't like your DataSet. Don't try to fix the problem by passing the report a server name, etc. Try to fix the DataSet instead.

You are making aliases of your column in your select statement for the dataset. Is that how the Crystal Report is? If the fields in Crystal Reports are named 'emp_id', 'emp_fname' and 'emp_lname', etc. then you should absolutely NOT alias them as 'Employee ID', 'First Name' and 'Last Name', etc.

Either your column collection has:

1. Too few, too many columns. You need the exact set the report was built on. (You can see this inside the Crystal Report designer.)
2. Badly named columns.
3. Columns with now different types. For example, you changed a column type in the database. If the report hasn't be updated to use this new column type, your dataset will fail if it doesn't pass in columns of the same type.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I'm sorry I can't understand them. My English is poor... I understand CODE better than English... ;)

Comment: OK, I understood what you said, but in this context, what exactly I need to do? I have tried everything...

Comment: Thnaks... I have done this... The only change is it prompts a server name, username, password, and database name. Still problem standby...

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is solved...

I added the table while filling the dataset.

```
da.Fill(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Instead of

```
da.Fill(ds);
```